# .comment {Display:none;} only working on 1 page

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Why would this only work on 1 page and not the rest?

My url is http://www.havasusears.com the page it is working on is the contact page but all the other pages still have a comment section

Comment: Your question is not at all clear, and the site you link to has no elements with a `comment` class.

Comment: I checked on your pages for the .comment element, no where to be found  Open the console and type in `$$(".comment")` the return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#comments {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: That did it! thanks... why did my method not work?

Comment: @user, because you were not selected the correct element..

Comment: because I used .comment instead of #comment right?

Comment: You should explain why what he did is incorrect instead of simply supplying the answer. `#` is used for id's while `.` is used for classes. And I'm guessing he forgot the 's' in 'comments'.